# Django form for a table of checkboxes

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a table-scheduler where people can pick the timeslots where they're free. I'm using django with a postgresql database. I have the below model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    monday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    tuesday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    wednesday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    thursday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    friday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    saturday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
    sunday = models.mulitpleChoiceField(choices= ["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])
```

The question is how do I create a form using modelForm that will give me a table, with rows = days and columns = timeslots, where the user can just check a checkbox to indicate when they are free.

Currently my forms.py just looks like this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = [
            "name",
            "monday",
            "tuesday",
            "wednesday",
            "thursday",
            "friday",
            "saturday",
            "sunday",
        ]
```

I'm still pretty new to django and only pick it up a month ago. Thanks for any advice that is given.

Comment: `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` is the same as `OneToOne` Relation and you should use it

Comment: I would design models this way: http://pastebin.com/T6pR9jrT

Comment: @doniyor Thanks for your input. What will the ModelForm that will be rendered though?

Comment: @doniyor and I just noticed, models do not have a multipleChoiceField option.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield

Comment: @doniyor yeah in your pastebin code, you have 
    
    `slot = models.multipleChoiceField(choices=["12-1", "1-2", "2-3"])`

multipleChoiceFields can only be used in forms. Currently the error is django.db.models has no attribute "MultipleChoiceField"

Comment: ok i just copied from your code, didnot check the field types

Comment: yeah it was my mistake. But I realised it didn't work only after I tried to make migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use two [datetime fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and the render the table with slots in the front-end with javascript. You would have to have a `start_time` and an `end_time` field.

This simplifies the model but means the model itself does not limit the time ranges (e.g Monday 12-13) and instead allows for any time to be selected. However, you could use [custom validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#writing-validators) to limit the time ranges that can be selected. I.e. so that they can only be selected in hour intervals or whatever your requirements are. I'm sure there is some online source that can help you with this but if you can't find any then let me know and I'll see if I can help.

I tried to find a javascript/jQuery library that already handles the time-picker functionality but was unable to find one. It would be fairly simple to create though. How I see it:

- Table of date ranges with each element having both a `data-start` and `data-end` attribute.
- On click of the time range, gather the two data attributes.
- On submit, stop propagation and submit the two date ranges to the view and save to `start_time` and `end_time`.